# What are the mandatory and optional address fields in geocode?

Tags: geocode

What are the mandatory and optional address fields in geocode?
 As the address format is different for different countries throughout the world, what is the format that needs to be used in geocode .Is there a specific format for it, like mandatory fields and optional fields in address.
Please let me know.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No specific format. Just give it some data and it will try its best to discern it. I have an app that the user inputs zip/postal code and it will retreive all the relevant info (city, state/province, country).